# How to check if application is uninstalled from android/ Iphone device

Tags: android, ios, web-services

Is there any way of checking from server if application on android phone or Iphone is uninstalled. In my application I want to delete records from Database if application is uninstalled from device.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of `Push Notification Services`.

Android return **`“error”:“NotRegistered”`** when you try to push notification on the device using `GCM 3.0` or later. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103960/how-to-know-if-application-data-is-cleared-or-application-is-uninstalled)

I'm not about `iOS`, `Windows Phone` and other mobile devices but I'm sure theirs services for push notification will definitely return such data on failure.

Thats the only possible way to achieve what you want as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can achieve this on iOS.

For Android please check,
[Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)